# Xamarin Image is NOT shown after compression

Tags: android, xamarin, bitmap, rotation, compression

in my xamarin forms project.
i have the Image Stream and i'm able to display the non compressed/Rotated images in my Images ListView.

but when i try to compress and rotate the images, the images are not displayed anymore in the Listview.

this is how i'm trying to compress every image

```
public static Stream RotateAndCompress(Stream imageStream, int rotationAngle)
    {
        Bitmap bp = BitmapFactory.DecodeStream(imageStream);
        MemoryStream outputStream = new MemoryStream();
        if (rotationAngle != 0)
        {
            var matrix = new Matrix();
            matrix.PostRotate(rotationAngle);
            using (var rotatedImage = Bitmap.CreateBitmap(bp, 0, 0, bp.Width, bp.Height, matrix, true))
            {
                rotatedImage.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Png, 80, outputStream);
                rotatedImage.Recycle();
            }

            return outputStream;
        }

        return imageStream;
    }
```

and in the VS Output

> 04-29 14:47:07.979 D/skia    ( 8497): --- SkAndroidCodec::NewFromStream returned null[0:] ImageLoaderSourceHandler: Image data was invalid: Xamarin.Forms.StreamImageSource

Comment: Are you sure that original imageStream is OK? have you tried to paint it without ny manipulation?

Comment: yes,i'm sure that the orginal image is shown in the ListView, but the compressed/rotated one is not shown. the Original image is taken from CameraPage Android Renderer , and its converted to stream then converted to StreamImageSource

Comment: are you sure that outputstream is a valid image?  Also, you might try resetting the outputstream to the begining using Seek